# ISampleGrabber callback is not being called

Tags: c#, wpf, directshow, directshow.net

I am using DirectShow.Net and trying to implement the ISampleGrabberCB on a class.

In order to set up the Grabber in the Graph, I follow this checklist:

1. Create a SampleGrabber object
2. Define the MediaType format (AMMediaType: Video, Rgb, VideoInfo) and set it into the SampleGrabber object. HRESULT is 0, so I think it's ok.
3. I set the callback with sampleGrabber.SetCallback(this, 0). I am passing "this" because the ISampleGrabber is implemented and defined in the class itself; the second parameter is 0 because I want the SampleCB method to be invoked.
4. Finally I'm adding the filter to the graph. The HRESULT is again 0.

However ISampleGrabber.SampleCB method is not being called.

Do you have any idea about the cause of this misbehavior?

**[Edit]**

I've found out what's going on here! But still I need some help. Both the webcams I own return a YUY2 subtype video format. As stated above, the code I am using forces the the MediaType to RGB24. At runtime I can see the HResult is 0, hence it's ok. But because they are "incompatible" the Sample Callback is never invoked. If I remove the Subtype explicit definition, the Callback is hit. However the frame I receive is a YUY2; it is not a valid Bitmap and for this reason it looks "damaged", "distorted".

At this point, I'd like to know either how I can successfully force the RGB24 format or how I can convert the video frame to the RGB24 format.

I've spent quite a bit of time on google trying to find a valid answer, but I had no luck.

Any idea?

Cheers.
Gianluca.

Comment: @Goz: The code is extensive and split into several functions. What part would you like to see?

Comment: WEll in light of your edit it would probably be good to see the part where you connect the filters

Answer (score 1):

You never mention that you connect Sample Grabber within the graph, and it is obviously essential. Since at some point you have the callback hit you of course connect it somehow, and still as you troubleshoot your media pipeline the way you connect and the effective filter graph topology are the first thing you want to check.

24-bit RGB subtype is a sort of "common denominator" of media types, so you can almost always get it on the sample grabber. To achieve this, you initialize sample grabber format with major type and subtype. You don't need to do format type there, however. Decoders to RGB 24 will be provided automatically.

All in all, if something does not work you want to know the topology you eventually get, and Sample Grabber needs proper initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a YUY2 to RGB converter.

Look up the [Color Converter DSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd443213%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  Set the input pin to YUY2 and set the output pin to RGB32.  Then add the sample grabber after that.

As the above filter is a DMO filter you'll need to use the [DirectShow DMO wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The link has a good example of using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I am moving my first steps on DirectShow, I am not sure on how to do what you say. Could you point out some link that could help me out or provide me with some snippet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Gianluca Colucci: Don't know how to do what?

Comment: I've managed to get it to work with: grpBuilder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Capture, MediaType.Video, this.capDev, null, (IBaseFilter)smpGrabber). Without it, the grabber was not connected, and I don't understand how it was working anyway. Further down I have: hr = grpBuilder.RenderStream(PinCategory.Preview, MediaType.Video, this.capDev, null, Renderer); It works. But is it conceptually right ?